# iterative OLS model runs very slow using Python Pandas and statsmodels ? ( improper use of dataframe - probably!)

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I use Stats-model and Pandas to automate an iterative process of running linear regressions for various combinations of variables. In total the combinations of variables reaches to 697,343. This is a lot of OLS calculation but I don’t expect it to take very long ( longer than 1 hr) .  X can be up to 18x18 and Y is always 18X1.

Can someone please advise if the code that I am using is not optimized? And possibly suggest a solution?

```
import time
import pandas
import statsmodels.api as sm
perm = pandas.read_pickle('C:\SharedData\Temp\ResultTestDataframes\perm')
BB=pandas.read_pickle('C:\SharedData\Temp\ResultTestDataframes\BB')
wdb_demog=pandas.read_pickle("C:/SharedData/Temp/ResultTestDataframes/wdb_demog")
wdb_hts=pandas.read_pickle("C:/SharedData/Temp/ResultTestDataframes/wdb_hts")

result_db= pandas.DataFrame(columns=('R-squared value','Adj. R-squared','F-statistic','Prob (F-statistic)','coefficeints','Variables'))
row=-1
for v in range(len(perm)):
    row+=1
    variables_columns=list(set(perm.loc[v]))
    if None in variables_columns:
        variables_columns.remove(None)   
    X= pandas.DataFrame(BB[variables_columns]).values.tolist()
    Y= pandas.DataFrame(BB[wdb_hts.columns.values[1]]).values.tolist()    
    model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
    results = model.fit()
    R=[round(results.rsquared,4),
       round(results.rsquared_adj,4),
       round(results.fvalue,4),
       round(results.f_pvalue,4),
       list(results.params),
       list(variables_columns)] 
    result_db.loc[row]= pandas.Series(R, index=result_db.columns)

result_db.to_pickle("C:/SharedData/Temp/ResultTestDataframes/TEST")
print "done! " + time.strftime("%c")

--------------------

# BB is the DataFrame (18 rows × 90 columns ) 
# perm is the DataFrame (697343 × 17) that has all the combinations of variables' . The X  (exogenous variables) will be built using the given combination of variables and the  data in BB data frame   
# wdb_hts is another data frame to read the variables name to construct the Y (endogenous variables)
```

Comment: You'll need to break this down further and show what you've found to be slow, I can see several issues in your code `variables_columns=list(set(perm.loc[v]))` are you expecting to have duplicate columns? also you are regenerating this on every iteration. Your X and Y df's are being created on lists of the numpy arrays why? could you not just do `X= pandas.DataFrame(BB[variables_columns])`? what's the significance of the second row value here: `BB[wdb_hts.columns.values[1]]`?

Comment: you are appending each row which causes a copy each time of n^2 operations; append to s list and concat at the end

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for taking your time and going through my code: 
`variables_columns` is just a container for different permutation of the initial variables. There are 18 initial variables and I am interested in all their meaningful combination which can be either one single element or any number of combinations of the various names. Saving this in pandas dataframe causes having duplicated `None` values (at any point where the length of this list is less than 18). So I used `variables_columns=list(set(perm.loc[v]))` to get rid of the None values. Its regenerated so I can construct the new`X ,Y`

Comment: @EdChum; as you correctly pointed out I could use `X= pandas.DataFrame(BB[variables_columns])` rather than the `X= pandas.DataFrame(BB[variables_columns]).values.tolist()`. Also I've used `BB[wdb_hts.columns.values[1]]` to create `Y`. I can certainly move it out of the loop.

Comment: @Jeff, Thanks for your advise on my code. Could you please clarify if you are referring to the line 'result_db.loc[row]= pandas.Series(R, index=result_db.columns)'  in which I am saving the results ? I saved the result in a list and then after the loop is finished saved that list in a new dataframe. It helped to reduce the run time. But it is still too long for such a code.